# STM32 Abort I2C Slave Receive

Tags: stm32, i2c, abort

I'd like to program an STM32L053 as an I2C Master and Slave at the same time (just for learning background). So I want to send data between two STM32L0.

My code is somethine like that:

```
Init_everything();
HAL_Slave_Receive_DMA(&hi2c, RxBuffer, 1);
...
HAL_Master_Transmit_DMA(&hi2c, TxBuffer, 1);
...
```

But I can't send the message. Without the slave receive it works well.
So is there any posibility to abort the reveive of the slave, transmit as master and start the slave receive again?
I can't find any functions like that.

Thanks

Comment: my code: `Init();Send();Receive();` Is it helpful?

Comment: The problem is, I don't know if I have to send first or receive first, so I have be all the time in receive mode and just interrupt it for a short time to send